# How to completely disable content highlighting for NavigationLink in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

```
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
            Image(systemName: "cloud.heavyrain")
                .foregroundColor(Color.accentColor)
                .font(.system(size: 66, weight: .regular))
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

In this example .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) modifier changes highlighting to very mild, but still visible effect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I came up with quite simple solution by creating a custom ButtonStyle without any modifiers in it:

```
struct EmptyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
    }
}
```

Comment: You know what? You really are a hero!! Such a beautiful solution! And so many ppl looking for this ...

Comment: Thanks you are the god I have been looking for..